# Custom nested form from parent in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have some nested formTypes like this :

`Form1` which includes `Form2` which includes `Form3`

Depending on some information (for example if the current user is an admin), i want to change the type of some field on `Form3`.

The problem is i don't know how to do that since there isn't `setOption` method in `$builder` object, that i could call from `Form1`.

Furthermore, i don't know how i should organize my forms, in fact `Form3` is include in some other forms too, and the fields are nearly the same each time, only a few have to change, that's why i made a `Form3` form to avoid redundancy.

Comment: One solution is to inject the context in your Form3 and use the is granted to adjust your builder (add fields or remove if he's admin or not for example)

Comment: That's working in that case but when i have to customize the form depending on other condition like some choice made in the controller, i will have to find another solution. I'm mading a big app and so i want the best start to avoid lot of changes later.

Comment: So instead of using directly the context you can maybe define a service in whitch you'll do all your tests and inject it in your form, this way you'll just have to edit your service if you've modification concerning the "rights" and it'll be reusable

Comment: You means settings some flags in to the service in the controller and `Form3` will check them to know what to do. That sounds not very clean to me :s. I hoped that i could dynamically modify forms object after they were created.

Comment: Yeah it's not very clean but i don't see other possibilies right now, and i don't think you can modify your form after his creation specially since your form3 is called when you create your form1 because they're embedded but let's see if other people have a better idea :)

Comment: I hope Symfony 2 can provide a solution to this kind of problem which shouldn't be one in such a Framework. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe this bundle ? it allows for multi-step forms.  
https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle

Comment: @topaz1008 I don't want to make a multi-step form. Do you have something else in mind ?

Comment: If the form should only be dynamic on the server you can just pass the formtype an options array, if it needs to be dynamic on the client (i.e. user selects something and some other fields change) than you need some javascript and ajax probably.

Comment: It is dynamic only on the server, passing params via constructor will work but i hoped a better solution because it means passing data from form to form (nested forms) until it reach The Form which need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use event subscriber for dynamically remove/add fields depending on some data.

Such event subscriber allow you to modify form data after form creation and it working on Form instance not on Type. More info you should find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html)

BTW About needed dependencies like security context or something you can [create given form type as service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) and inject needed object

Comment: I still not see how to go on with that, in fact it make possible modifying form in another place than in builderForm mehod, but i don't see how does it is a good way. I do not see on which condition the event class will modify my field type or not. Maybe the problem has just moved.